# Display alert before deleting

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I got an action-link passing an ID to a Deletemethod in my controller.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteContent", new { xid = item.Id })
```

I would like som kind of "confirm action"-alert that gets triggered when the link is clicked.
Lets say the alert has two options, "Delete" and "Cancel".

If the user hits cancel I dont want the method to excecute.

Any tips on how to accomplish that?

Comment: Javascript alert confirmation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a confirm box

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteContent", new { xid = item.Id,onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');" })
```

Comment: Thank you!
For some reason the above code did nor work for me. But with help from you i found this code:
|@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteContent", new { xid = item.Id}, new {onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" })

That worked fine! Thanks again!

The difference is the added "new"